# Python 2.7, requests, login into onlydomains.com site

Tags: python, authentication, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Since couple of days I try to login into `www.onlydomains.com` site to retrieve my domain lists into a script.
I've already have something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests, sys, re, whois
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def onlydomains():
    with requests.Session() as c:
        PASSWORD = 'my%password'
        USERNAME = 'my_username'
        URL = 'https://www.onlydomains.com/account/login'
        c.get(URL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(c.get(URL).text, "lxml")

        csrf = soup.find("input", value=True)["value"]

    login_data = {
        'csrfToken' : csrf,
        'username' : USERNAME,
        'password' : PASSWORD,
        'submit' : 'Submit',}

    r = c.post(URL, data=login_data, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'})
    r = c.get('https://onlydomains.secure-admin.com/domain/index')
    print r.text

onlydomains()
```

And it does not working for me because I've always get

```
 > ./onlydomains.py

    <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title>Login / Sign Up - OnlyDomains</title>
```

Any ideas what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at what is returned from the post you can see a `window.location = some_url`:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){

                    setTimeout(function(){

                            window.location = 'https://onlydomains.secure-admin.com/dashboard/index?_srs_=v42oadi4cAuxIM4PHc5IdgU%5CdXd3AjswsOraTLjynso%3D';;


                    },1000);
                });
            </script>
```

You can use that to get to the page:

```
  patt = re.compile("window.location\s+=\s+'(http.*)'")

  with requests.Session() as s:
        PASSWORD = 'user'
        USERNAME = "pass"
        URL = 'https://www.onlydomains.com/account/login'
        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(URL).text, "lxml")
        csrf = soup.select_one("input[name=csrfToken]")["value"]

    login_data = {
        'csrfToken' : csrf,
        'username' : USERNAME,
        'password' : PASSWORD}


    r = c.post(URL, data=login_data, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'})

    url = patt.search(r.text).group(1)
    r = s.get(url).text
    print(r)
```

If we run the code and print the `data-original-title` attribute from the main content, you can see we are at the dashborad page:

```
In [5]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ...:         PASSWORD = 'xxxxxx'
   ...:         USERNAME = "xxxxxxxxxx"
   ...:         URL = 'https://www.onlydomains.com/account/login'
   ...:         soup = BeautifulSoup(c.get(URL).text, "lxml")
   ...:         csrf = soup.select_one("input[name=csrfToken]")["value"]
   ...:         login_data = {
   ...:         'csrfToken' : csrf,
   ...:         'username' : USERNAME,
   ...:         'password' : PASSWORD}
   ...:         r = s.post(URL, data=login_data, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'})
   ...:         url = patt.search(r.text).group(1)
   ...:         r = s.get(url).text
   ...:         soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"lxml")
   ...:         print(soup.select_one("h1.PageTitle.visible-xs i.fa.fa-info-circle")["data-original-title"])
   ...:     

Welcome to your Dashboard! Here you have a general overview of what's happening and how to manage your domain assets.
```

Comment: Sorry but i'm not fimiliar with `patt.search(r.text).group(1)`
I've get:
`url = patt.search(r.text).group(1)
NameError: global name 'patt' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the regex, I will edit in a bit

Comment: Ok, last question... How i can stay logged in on that page and navigate into another subpage eq `https://onlydomains.secure-admin.com/domain/index`?

Comment: @the_me, just  simply, `s.get("https://onlydomains.secure-admin.com/domain/index")`

Comment: I've got:
[link](http://pastebin.com/DNAaHGNf)
and get:
`<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title>Login / Sign Up - OnlyDomains</title>`

Answer (score -1):

I think that the best way to solve your problem will be with selenium(i remember  do something like what you want to do with BS but i don´t remember how now)

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get('http://www.example.com')

username = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys('user1')

password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('secret')

form = browser.find_element_by_id('loginForm')
form.submit()
```

This will make you able to load the next page that should contain the information that you want :)

Comment: Selenium work's, yesterday i've tried with success. But i don't want to open firefox/chromium every  time. It will be server script. And I work on linux. ;)